# How to disable Gcloud ports OR Why does google cloud compute engine have so many ports filtered or open?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Using gcloud compute engine to run several interconnected services

1. IPFS node (glcoud compute engine)
2. Postgres database (gcloud SQL)
3. Nginx + Docker app (gcloud compute engine)

In attempting to forward and open correct ports for service interconnectivity, I found some issues. Specifically when opening ports for non web or non ssh ports, and/or listening to non-standard web ports using NginX (eg. for forwarding of http requests on non-standard ports to the docker container).

Using Nmap, I discovered over 900 ports are in 'filtered' state. I'm assuming because Google cloud virtual hosting is using `bc.googleusercontent.com` as primary host.

This is an example: Port 8020 is being filtered as 'intu-ec-svcdisc' service. I found it to be this service [INTUIT service discoverer](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-number/intu-ec-svcdisc/).

I'm hoping to discover a way to open several of these ports that I need.

[image: Glcoud compute engine port scan]

Comment: what specific "nmap" command (without the IP) are you running ?  are you scanning from the public internet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man.html#:%7E:text=Filtered%20means%20that%20a%20firewall,open%20up%20at%20any%20time.)

> Filtered means that a firewall, filter, or other network obstacle is blocking the port so that Nmap cannot tell whether it is open or closed. Closed ports have no application listening on them, though they could open up at any time.

By default, GCP only allows port 22/tcp & 3389/tcp incoming traffic to all your instances, however you have the option to tag your GCE resourse with `http-server` and/or `https-server` to allow ports 80/tcp & 443/tcp as well.

What you are seeing on your nmap output is exactly those ports open / closed because those can actually reach your GCE instance, but GCP firewall is blocking additional incoming traffic by default, and therefore you see this as "filtered".

You would need to open your desired ports on [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) by using the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) or [video](https://youtu.be/F1pWN3Lk7og?t=557), keep in mind that you can also have enabled a firewall inside your operating system, that could be turning those requests away.